# Rebooting my EC2 instance empties my www/html folder

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have created an environment with Elastic Beanstalk with a EC2 instance with PHP installed: my files are in /var/www/html.

First I allowed Auto-Scaling/Load balancer but when the auto-scaling triggered, it created another instance and terminated the old one. And then I realized, the new one was not a clone of the old one : I lost all my config and my files, while I did attached a SSD root volume in my EB config.

I tried again and I created an AMI image which I included in my EB config (in Custom AMI ID). This time my config stays but my folder /var/www/html is emptied and replaced by default index.html files.

**1.** Is it supposed to happen ? I thought the auto scaling created a cloned of the instance ?

So I decided to disable auto scaling / load balancer and to work on a single instance mode. But then even when I reboot my EC2 instance, the config is preserved but my whole folder /var/www/html is emptied again and only the default files are inside.

**2.** Why ? There is an EBS volume attached to my instance (EB did that automatically), so it should not happen, if I understand correctly how it works.

Maybe it is the same issue for both but I really don't get why my files are deleted.

Thanks a lot for your help !
Romain

Comment: "But then even when I reboot my EC2 instance, the config is preserved but my whole folder /var/www/html is emptied": double-check really reboot or stop-start? The behavior can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoscaling uses an AMI to launch new instances, and AMIs are no more than snapshots of EC2 instances at a certain point in time. Because of this, every time Autoscaling launches a new instance, any differences between the AMI and the current desired state must be applied in boot time prior to receive new traffic.

ElasticBeanstalk provides tools to manage application deployments integrated into the Autoscaling dynamic and also manage instance configurations. Sometimes these configurations become too complex to achieve during bootstrap using the EB tools and there is when custom AMIs come handy.

If you SSH into an autoscaling instance and start manually performing actions out of the ElasticBeanstalk toolstack's scope, all of those changes will be lost in the next Autoscaling event unless you save an updated AMI from your instance and apply it to your Autoscaling Group.

Comment: That's very clear, thanks.Then I will configure using eb-config files to be sure that at each new instance, right content and config are included.